# Is it possible to make an app for android + iOS that is actually just a web app?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I'm enjoying web development and I want to make an "app" to try my hand at mobile phone dev. Learning Java/AppleCode isn't feasible right now, so would it be possible to make a website that runs as an app on a phone? And have that app do the things people want apps to do, like integrate with your phone's calendar, receive notifications in the notification bar at the top (Android), etc...??

Comment: Have you ever heard about `Phonegap` ? http://phonegap.com/

Comment: this might interest you: a tutorial to build android/ios using html 5 https://dzone.com/articles/iosandroid-app-24-hours-html5

Comment: @vincent phonegap is basically cordova but for people who have trouble using cordova. cordova is command line while phonegap is just a GUI with adobe branding on it (although you need to use the command line to add platforms and plugins)

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable that is nice to know, then the developers may choose their preference whether go hardcore or not.

Comment: @vincent, i wouldn't call it hardcore. Only things phonegap has that cordova doesn't is a gui tool for running it on a webserver and accessing it using the phonegap dev app in your app store to test it. I haven't been able to spot any reason to use phonegap over cordova except that cordova enforces the use of the terminal to build or add plugins and platforms

Answer (score 3):

[Yes](https://cordova.apache.org/).

Apache cordova will do the trick but you (of course) can't have php running, only html and javascript are supported (and the code in which the app is built).

**Featueres :**

- Free :)
- Code for multiple platforms in html and js.
- Tons of plugins to do all kind of stuff for you.
- Can (with a little modification of content security policy) load pages from a remote server.

**Downsides :**

- Not the performance of normal code.
- Only communication between app code and js is using callbacks, this results in true **Callback Hell**.
- All app code runs asynchronously while js code doesn't.
- Installation is not a simple .exe but an actual guide (i managed to screw it up, had to system restore to easily remove created files. But it should be rather simple).

**Supported Platforms :**

- android
- ios, can't compile for ios on non-apple though (thanks apple!)
- browser (basically webserver)
- windows
- windows 8 app
- windows phone 8
- blackberry 10
- and more...

Comment: Wow! That's so cool! I thought the answer was going to be a long drawn out and painful "No, and here's why..."

Comment: @whatwhatwhat  Native code is computer programming (code) that is compiled to run with a particular processor (such as an Intel x86-class processor) and its set of instructions. If the same program is run on a computer with a different processor, software can be provided so that the computer emulates the original processor.
i just searced the web

Comment: Hm....I don't fully understand that @RashimCatalanDhaubanjar but I'll do some googleing meeshelf.

Comment: I ment the code that the app runs on, for android it's java. It's cordova jargon

Comment: +1 also like to add that another upside is 'instant deployment' (no waiting for approval for platforms such as iOS)

Comment: You can make a js function that uses ajax and one of the many filemanager plugins of cordova to update but you need to wait for the approval of that update. This is not against the terms of service because the terms of service does not allow self-updating of **binary** code, this does not apply to resources of the app